# react usestate setvalue before async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-context

Trying out react context api for the first time. Here is my react code using the context api

```
  const [valChanged, setValChanged] = useState(false);

  async function modalSave() {
    await setValChanged(true);// STEP 1
    await onEventSave();// This involves saving values to backend (async) STEP 2
  }
```

the onEventSave() async operation relies on valChanged value on previous step and therefore it has to be set to true before onEventSave is invoked. (step 1 has to be completed and its value set to true, before STEP 2 is invoked)

is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using hooks, there is no `setState` callback function, so you can do it with `useEffect`, like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    onEventSave();
},[valChanged]);
```

The above function will be called whenever the `valChanged` is changed